# What happens if you run Kosaraju’s algorithm on a DAG?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, algorithm-analysis

What happens if you run [Kosaraju’s algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosaraju%27s_algorithm) for finding strongly connected components of directed graphs on a DAG?

Comment: What do you think of it? What is your specific question?

Comment: Try it and see what happens!

Answer (score 3):

We should think about the property of SCC(strongly connected component)

A directed graph $G(V, E)$ is acyclic if and only if $G$ has no SCCs with more that one vertex. Because a directed cycle is SCC by definition of the cycle.

Hence, the result of the **Kosaraju’s algorithm on a DAG** will return $|V|$ trivial SCCs. In other words, it returns $\{\{v\}\mid v\in V\}$.